# Trouble with re-binding DataGridView after a cell is edited

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView`, which is part of a custom control. This custom control's interface exposes a property which only takes a `DataTable` which can be set as the `DataSource` for the DataGridView.

When the user edits the contents of one of the cells, I want to set a special value in the last column, stating that the row has been modified.

I expose a public event from the custom control for the DataGridView's `CellEndEdit` event. In a form that uses this control, I subscribe to this event with the following event handler:

```
private void myCustomControl_CellEndEdit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // plan of attack:
    // - copy the DataTable into a new temporary one
    // - modify the appropriate column in the affected row
    // - bind the new table to the control

    // get the row and column indexes of the modified cell
    int rowIndex = ((DataGridViewCellEventArgs)e).RowIndex;
    int colIndex = ((DataGridViewCellEventArgs)e).ColumnIndex;
   
    DataTable temp = this.dataTable.dataSource.Copy();
    temp.Rows[rowIndex][colIndex] = "Modified";

    // bind the modified table
    CurrencyManager cm = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[dataTable.dataSource];
    cm.SuspendBinding();
    myCustomControl.dataSource = temp; // this is the offending line
    cm.ResumeBinding();        
}
```

This throws the following exception:

[image]

As shown in the code snippet above, I have tried to suspend the binding to solve this problem, but to no avail. What might be the issue?

Comment: Also, I question why “copy” the `DataSource`? this seems unnecessary. I would think the error would be on the line… `temp.Rows[rowIndex][colIndex] = "Modified";` … however since this is a “copy” of the data source, then it may be trickling down to when the data source changes. Have you tried this “without” copying the original data source as it appears completely unnecessary?

Comment: @JohnG I was starting to think that as well. I will try to modify the `DataSource` directly.

Answer (score 0):

I don`t know how your code works, but I think that use *BindingSource* as *DataSource* in your *DataGridView* could be the solution to your problem.

```
public class MyDataGridView : Form
{
  private BindingSource bindingDataSource = new BindingSource();
  private DataTable myDataTable; 

  public MyDataGridView()
  {
      InitializeComponent();
     
      //Set Data Source to DataTable
      bindingDataSource.DataSource = myDataTable; 

      //Use BindingSource as DataSource
      this.dataGridView.DataSource = bindingDataSource;
  }
  
  //...

  private void myCustomControl_CellEndEdit(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     //Update your datatable values 
     this.myDataTable.Rows[colIndex].Value = "Modified";

     //Refresh your grid data binding
     this.bindingDataSource.ResetBindings(metadataChanged: false);
     this.dataGridView.Refresh();
  }
}
```